# Chrome web developer tools focus console input with keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I can open developer tools console using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+J</kbd> in chrome developer tools. But how can I focus on the input to start typing using the keyboard?

Since the cursor isn't at the input box most times. I am currently having to click at the console input box to start typing.

Comment: It's `Ctrl \`` (the backtick), you can see it in the shortcuts panel in devtools setting UI.

Answer (score 0):

After opening the devtools console, try hitting **Tab**, it will put the focus on the console input.

Comment: not working for me